# how to run sites remotely on tfs server

Tags: tfs

How to run ASP.NET sites remotely on tfs server?

Comment: I have asp.net website. I've heard it can be runned remotely.

Comment: I have never ever worked with tfs expect check out new solution

Comment: Though I understand that @user418251 may not be a native English speaker, there's just not enough here to divine what he's trying to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify: you have created a custom ASP.Net website. You want to deploy this to a remote machine. If that is what you want, you can use MSDeploy for that purpose: http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/FT14.

Or do you want something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run some page of an arbitrary ASP.NET website during an automated build, we may have same requirements ;) I suggest put some web services instead of web pages on your ASP.NET website and then run those web services through a custom CodeActivity or custom build workflow. You can insert this custom activity wherever in your build process template you want.